# How to flatten a tuple, as flatMap is not defined over tuples?

Tags: scala, tuples

For an example, how to convert `((1,"one"),2)` to `(1,"one",2)`?

I tried to use flatMap, but flatMap is not defined on tuple

```
scala> val a= ((1,"one"),2)
a: ((Int, String), Int) = ((1,one),2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

flatMap is defined in Shapeless 2.0 library:

https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0

```
((23, "foo"), (), (true, 2.0)) flatMap identity
```

Or you can convert tuple to iterator, but types will be lost in that case

```
((23, "foo"), (), (true, 2.0)).productIterator
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out HLists in the [Shapeless library](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#hlist-style-operations-on-standard-scala-tuples).  This is a very popular library maintained by one of the smartest Scala guys around.

In particular this example:

```
import syntax.std.tuple._
scala> (23, "foo") :+ true
res6: (Int, String, Boolean) = (23,foo,true)
```

You can make a function where you take the first part of the outer tuple (aka the inner tuple) and add the second part of the outer tuple.  In the background the Shapeless library will be converting to and from HLists.

Answer (score 2):

There's not a lot you can do there. Tuples are not collections and furthermore, there's no real relationship between the native Tuple classes, such that you can convert from an m-tuple to an n-tuple that's related in some way. The best you can really do is unpack the tuple and then repack it how you like:

```
val ((a, b), c) = ((1, "one"), 2)
val repacked = (a, b, c)
```

In most cases, I run into this at the input of a function or in a `match`, in which case you can use a `case` to unpack the tuple fairly painlessly.

It's tough to tell your use case from the brevity of your question, but if you really want to deal with tuple-like data structures flexibly and programmatically, you may want to look into [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0).